# How to include font-awesom in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, font-awesome

I'm tring to include font-awesom in jQuery Mobile and do not work. ¿is it possible? or I need a "jquery mobile version" of font awesom??

Comment: What doesn't work? It is a bit unclear. Can't include it? Doesn't look right for the users?

Answer (score 0):

Andy Mathews provides a jQuery Mobile Icon pack which includes Font Awsome and the CSS to use it directly:

http://andymatthews.net/read/2012/04/04/Font-Awesome-icons-now-included-in-jQuery-Mobile-Icon-Pack

Answer (score 0):

**Another** resource for using font awesome icons in jQuery mobile

Article & Info: http://www.dotcastle.com/blog/51/default/font-awesome-icons-for-jquery-mobile

Demo: http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/dotcastle/jquery-mobile-font-awesome/blob/master/index.html

Comment: article and info is a dead link.  demo is just columns of icons but no implementation specific to jqm.